# 301 htaccess with %20 in target URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, whitespace

I need to manage some URL in query string. The landing URL contains space (%20).
I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=([0-9]+)&pagenumber=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^[OLD-SLUG]$ https://www.domain-site.it/Content/Images/uploaded/[TEXT-01]%20[TEXT-02]%20[TEXT-03].pdf? [R=301,L]
```

But the result is that the URL redirects to:

```
https://www.domain-site.it/Content/Images/uploaded/[TEXT-01]50[TEXT-02]50[TEXT-03].pdf
```

What's wrong?

Thanks all

Comment: Your rewrite rule is having %20 in it? Or its a typo, could you please elaborate more on it.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, my rewrite rule has %20 in the path, somenting like this:
https://www.domain-site.it/Content/Images/uploaded/Text%20Text%20Text%20Text.pdf
tks

Comment: Try using NE flag. `[R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: Hi Amit Verna, thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in this way:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(\S*)\s/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=([0-9]+)&pagenumber=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^old-slug$ https://www.domain-site.it/Content/Images/uploaded/[TEXT-01]\%20[TEXT-02]\%20[TEXT-03].pdf? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Tks all!

Answer (score 0):

`%N`, with `(0 <= N <= 9)`, is the syntax for back references to the capture groups of the previous RewriteCond.

So `%2` is referring to what you captured with `pagenumber=([0-9]+)`.

You need to escape the percent character with a backslash, for it to be meant literal.

```
RewriteRule ^[OLD-SLUG]$ .../[TEXT-01]\%20[TEXT-02]\%20[TEXT-03].pdf? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: (Or you stop capturing these parts in the first place, since it does not look like you are actually using these values in your substitution URL. So by removing the capturing braces, you should be able to use %1, %2 without escaping again. But %0 would still need escaping, if that ever occurred in a substitution URL, because that refers back to the whole string matched by the RewriteCond, without any grouping.)

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your support. If I review the rule in this way, as you suggested, it works:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^donne-straordinarie$ https://www.domain-site.it/Content/Images/uploaded/Piano%20Opera%20Donne.pdf? [R=301,L]
I tried with the escape, but it doesn't work. I don't understand why.
Tks a lot